# Azure AD SSO using SAML2 with Amazon ELB SSL

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, azure

I am trying to setup SSO using Azure AD. Our aplication is a spring boot application deployed on Amazon ECS.

For this I have refered https://dummybot.medium.com/saml-integration-with-spring-boot-spring-security-microsoft-azure-ad-b9610bdb78b9, which uses Spring Security SAML2 with Spring Boot.

In our case the application exposes the port 8080 from docker container and doesn't have its own SSL configuration. We are using Amazon ELB as load balancer in which the SSL is configured and through the load balancer we can access the application `https://our-domain.com`

When testing application locally I am able to login successfully when `https://localhost:8443/saml/sso` is added as a reply Url in Azure AD.

When I add only the https://our-domain.com/saml/sso as reply URL and try logging in while executing application locally, I get this error:

[correct http protocol and port in AD request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B71Gs.png)

which is expected as we dont have `https://localhost:8080/..` as white listed reply URL in Azure AD now.

But what I noticed here in the error message is `https://localhost:8080/...` doesn't match the reply URL, which is correct, but there is no change in HTTP protocol or port 8080 which I am trying to access.

But, When I try to access the application deployed on AWS ECS using `https://our-domain.com`, I am successfully redirected to login page, but there I get this error.
[incorrect http protocol and port in AD request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DSou.png)

Where I can see HTTP protocol has been changed from https to http and the port is passed in the request as 8443.

I could see only in our AWS ELB which has configuration for SSL certificate and has a HTTPS listener 8443, and I am suspecting it is due to this the incorrect reply URL is passed by the Spring Security in the Azure AD Authentication request.
[Amazon ELB configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL6Od.png)

I have tried to find solution for this and found an issue reported in Spring-Security-Saml project at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/447, which talks about SAMLContextProviderLB as the context provider bean.

More details in Spring-Security SAML Extension documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-load-balancing

Although it is mentioned in the documentation for latest version of Spring-Security SAML Extension, I cant find this class, but it is available in older 1.0.x version of extension. Hence I am not able to use it.

Can someone please provide any pointers to fix this issue..

Thanks